# What is the meaning of f in printf?

Tags: c

What is the meaning of "f" in C's printf?

Comment: I just started learning C programming... I apologize if this question is silly...

Comment: What's vague or ambiguous about the question?  How is it not reasonably answerable?  There certainly are reasonable answers. (It also seems funny that K-ballo was one of the people who closed this despite having the accepted answer.)

Comment: It is a real question, but one that could be quickly Googled (as many other questions): https://www.google.com/search?q=What+is+the+meaning+of+"f"+in+C%27s+printf therefore it is duplicate so I vote to close, but from a different reason.

Comment: Google-ability should not be the basis for closing a question.  Google indexes StackOverflow; therefore all questions and answers on SO can implicitly be searched for on Google.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `f` in `printf` stands for **formatted**, its used for printing with formatted output.

Comment: Thanks... So if I write just print, will it work...

Comment: @Sharan Chandran: There is no `print` function in C standard library.

Comment: @SharanChandran The non-formatted version is just called `puts`.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, the *trailing* `f` indicates formatted output (or formatted input for functions in the `scanf` family).

However, I'll add that the distinction matters because it's important for callers to know that the string is expected to have format-specifier semantics.  For example, do not do this:

```
char* s = get_some_user_input();
printf(s); // WRONG.  Instead use: printf("%s", s) or fputs(stdout, s)
```

If `s` happens to contain `%` characters, printing it directly with `printf` can cause it to access non-existent arguments, leading to undefined behavior (and this is a cause for some security vulnerabilities).  Keep this naming convention in mind if you ever define your own `printf`-like variadic functions.

Answer (score 0):

printf allows for formatting, while print doesnt. Also, print doesn't exist in C. I don't even know what printg is.

Comment: I don't know what `print` is either...

Comment: yeah, i just remembered that it doesn't exist too :) been a long time since ive coded anything in straight up c

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, printf stands for "Print formatted data to stdout".

Comment: Just "print formatted" -- `stdout` is just taken for granted as long as you don't specify otherwise with `fprintf`.